# Rails not saving checkbox input from model with many-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, associations, simple-form

I have two models Teacher and Student, and I established a HABTM relationship between two of them. I have a form for each of them to create a new record in the database. For example, in the create teacher form, the user can enter the teacher's name as input, and tick checkboxes containing the names of different students. If the user ticks a box, the input will not be saved, but if the checkbox is left blank and the user simply inputs the name, a new record is saved. Weirdly enough, if the user updates the teacher, that's only time the user can choose students to include in the teacher's record.

This is how some of the methods in `TeacherController` looks like:

```
def new
  @teacher = current_user.teachers.build
end

def create
  @teacher = current_user.teachers.build(teacher_params)

  if @teacher.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def edit
end

def update
  if @teacher.update(teacher_params)
    redirect_to teacher_path(@teacher)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

private
  def teacher_params
    params.require(:teacher).permit(:name, :student_ids => [])
  end

  def search_teacher
    @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Below is the form I use to create a new teacher and update an existing teacher:

```
<%= simple_form_for @teacher do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, label: "Teacher's Name" %>
  <label>Students</label>
  <br>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :student_ids, Student.all, :id, :name %>
  <br>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

It might also help noting that I only encountered this problem after introducing user authentication with `devise` in my application.

Comment: can you create a [gist](http://gist.github.com) with the whole server log when you submit the form?

Comment: also apologies, maybe it's just me, but i'm finding it difficult to comprehend what are you trying to achieve and where you are stuck in the introduction paragraph you wrote. Can you update exactly what's the goal, what's the behavior, and what you are expecting?

Comment: In else block (before render 'new') add a line - `Rails.logger.info("#{@teacher.errors.full_messages}")`, then please check and report with server log

Comment: @kiddorails Basically, the form has a name input, and a checkbox containing all the names of the students. The user can pick the students he wishes to associate with that teacher in that form. The problem with my application is whenever the user ticks the checkbox, the new record for teacher will not be saved. The same form is used to update an existing teacher record, and for some reason, ticking the checkbox doesn't have the same problem as the create new teacher.

Comment: @kiddorails, I got this message: `[Students is invalid]`.

Comment: Change the association to `has_and_belongs_to_many :students, inverse_of: :teacher` and `has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers, inverse_of :student` correspondingly and try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172348/discussion-between-kiddorails-and-bargain23).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow steps like this

in the controller

```
def create
   @teacher = Teacher.new(teacher_params)
   @teacher.user= current_user
   if @teacher.save
     # code
   else
     # code
   end
end

private
def teacher_params
   params.require(:teacher).permit(:name, student_ids: [])
end
```

The form

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :student_ids, Student.all, :id, :name do |cb| %>
    <% cb.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {cb.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cb.text } %>
<% end %>
```

See the [**`collection_check_boxes`**](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes) and this relationship.

If don't work it would be better to post Models with relationships.

Comment: May I know what the `job_params` argument is?

Comment: Ohh! it was a typing mistake, it will be `teacher_params` I mean strong parameters method